# Why are Ideals identified with the concept of zeros?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

**I'm trying to gain intuition on the *ideal* in my rings and fields course, but I'm struggling with some underlying concepts.**

*In our definition, rings do not need unity. Also, lets stick with two sided ideals*

**Things I understand (atleast at surface level):**

- An ideal $I$ is a subring of $R$ with the additional abosorbtion property $rx \in I$ for $ x \in I, r \in R$.
- Ideals are used to "partition" the ring when thinking of cosets using the quotient ring $$R/I:=\{r+I|r\in R\}$$
- Each coset, is an equivalence class with the relation $$x\sim y \Leftrightarrow x-y\in I$$
  which is a result of the fact that if $r,s\in R$ and $(r+I)\cap(s+I)\ne \emptyset$ then $r+I=s+I$.
- The kernel of a ring homomorphism can be proven to be a subring with an additional absorbtion property, hence it is also an ideal.
- We can also construct a ring homomorphism for any ideal $I$ such that $\ker f =I$ by choosing surjective ring homomorphism
  $$ f:R \to R/I \\r\mapsto \bar{r}$$
- The first isomorphism theorem

**Things I dont understand (or struggle to grasp):**

- Why do we identify $0$ with the elements of an ideal? In the example of $$R[x]/(x^2+1)$$ which create the field of complex numbers, it is depdendent on realizing that $x^2+1=0 \implies x^2=-1$ in this context.
- What is the intutition for the ideal as a basic principle without considering its use in a quotient ring?
- How can we define $R/I$ for any ideal $I\subset R$, whether or not $I = \ker f$ for some ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The key point is : the kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal, and every ideal is the kernel of a ring homeomorphism. Ideals are the good structures to make quotients (similarly as normal subgroups are for group homomorphisms).

Comment: The key properties of $0$: $0+0=0$, $0\cdot a=a\cdot 0=0$. $x-y=0\to x=y$.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe But can we consider ideals of a ring as some "null" part of the ring without thinking of ring homomorphisms, the kernel, and the quotient ring?

Comment: @Hushus46 No, I would not say that ideals are some null part of a ring. Until you make the quotient, obviously.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Okay, so lets say we have a quotient. It will be cosets of the form $r+I$ for $r\in R$. This partitions the ring. As I'm trying to understand, every element in a coset is reduced to the generator $r$ of the coset, something like this picture: http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~john/MT4517/Diagrams/L8_1.gif

Is this collapsing a "zero" property?

Comment: @DonThousand So what you're saying is because Ideals are an additive subgroup, have the absorbtion property , then they are like "0". The $x-y$ equation you wrote is equivalent to the fact that elements in the Ideal are considered the same?

Comment: @Hushus46 something to that effect, yes/

Comment: @DonThousand Hmm.. I'm going to have to ponder upon this a bit longer, thanks for the help

Comment: @Hushus46 Yes, *in the quotient* the elements of $I$ are mapped to $0$. So indeed, the elements of $I$ can be seen as the elements that are mapped to $0$ in $R/I$ (that's why every ideal is the kernel of a ring homomorphism, precisely of $R \rightarrow R/I$). But what I wanted to underline is the fact that ideals exist before talking about quotients : when you have a ring, it has ideals, which are just subsets with some properties. And if you just look as ideals as subsets of a ring, there is no real link with some "null" property.